# getting the error while creating the project in blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry-simulator

I am using the blackberry application and I am getting the error while creating the project in blackberry

Error:

> InvalidRegex: Pattern value
>   '([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*' is not a valid regular
>   expression.

The reported error was:

> ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '-'.' at column '{2}'.

I am able to run the simulator, but not getting my application in the download folder of it.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java 7 and install JDK 1.6, then run Eclipse plugin with it. There is a bug in the latest plugin for Eclipse.

This is, in fact, not a valid regular expression. It should probably be
`([a-zA-Z_]{1,63}[\s\-a-zA-Z_0-9.]{0,63}[;]?)*`

This is a quote from RIM: "The problem is with Java 1.7, which the plugin doesn't currently support. You will need to use Java 1.6 32bit for development with the Eclipse plugin." ([source](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/InvalidRegex-Pattern-value-a-zA-Z-1-63-a-zA-Z-0-9-0-63-is-not-a/td-p/944343/page/2))